# Get all columns from an SQL Table without Computed Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

I'm running SQL Server 2008 and having to load the table without computed columns in it, i.e. something like

> SELECT (ALL COLUMNS WITHOUT COMPUTED COLUMNS) FROM MY_TABLE

Is that possible doing so? What could be other work around if I need to deselect computed columns from being loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about looking at using the iscomputed column from [syscolumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260398%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and dynamic sql?

```
iscomputed (int)

Flag indicating whether the column is computed: 

0 = Noncomputed.

1 = Computed.
```

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE TADA(
  A INT,
  B INT,
  C AS (A+B)
 );
INSERT INTO TADA (A,B) VALUES (1,2);

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(500) = 'TADA'
DECLARE @ColumnNames VARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @ColumnNames = COALESCE(@ColumnNames + ',','') + col.name
FROM sysobjects obj 
INNER JOIN syscolumns col ON obj.id = col.id 
WHERE obj.name = @TableName
AND col.iscomputed = 0

EXEC ('SELECT ' + @ColumnNames + ' FROM ' + @TableName)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41031/12)